# I have a button that down-votes a initial set number by 1 when clicked.But I want it to stop at 0

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my Quote class I have set the up-vote and down-vote properties to initial value of 0

```
export class Quote {
    showDescription: boolean;
    upvotes: number;
    downvotes: number;
    constructor(
    public content:string,
    public publisher:string,
    public author:string,
    public datePublished:Date
    ) {
        this.showDescription = false;
        this.upvotes =  0;
        this.downvotes = 0;
    }
}
```

Below is my HTML button

```
<li *ngFor = 'let quote of quotes; let i = index' quotes>
<div class="col-md-6 downvotes">
................

    <img src="assets/down-arrow.png" alt="" (click)="downVote(i)">
    <span >{{quote.downvotes}}</span>

...................
</div>
</li>
```

This how I'm calling the downvote function when button is clicked

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Quote } from '../quote'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quote',
  templateUrl: './quote.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quote.component.css']
})

export class QuoteComponent implements OnInit {
............

  downVote(index:number) {
  this.quotes[index].downvotes -= 1;

.................

}
```

Comment: you could not simply wrap your this.quotes[index].downvotes -= 1; with an if statement? maybe I miss the point

Answer (score 0):

```
this.quotes[index].downvotes -= 1;
if (this.quotes[index].downvotes < 0) this.quotes[index].downvotes = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, the early return pattern below is just another option to consider.

```
downVote(index:number) {
  if(this.quotes[index].downvotes === 0)
    return;
  this.quotes[index].downvotes -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Doing it with **pointer-events** using **ngClass**.

**In your .html**

```
<li *ngFor = 'let quote of quotes; let i = index' quotes>
 <div class="col-md-6 downvotes">
  <img src="assets/down-arrow.png" alt="" [ngClass]="{quotes[index]<=0?'click-disabled':'click-enabled'}" (click)="downVote(i)">
  <span >{{quote.downvotes}}</span>
 </div>
</li>
```

**In style.css**

```
.click-disabled{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.click-enabled{
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Method 2:**

Checking when the click is made and returning nothing if the condition matches.
P.s -  You can use this method to add toast messages too. I would recommend this method.

```
downVote(index:number) {
  if(this.quotes[index].downvotes === 0)
    return;
  --this.quotes[index].downvotes;
}
```